# Error while creating an in-memory graph in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am currently trying to reproduce an example from the graph data science developer guide but i am getting an weird error when trying to create an in-memory using the code from the guide.

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
'marvel_model_data',
{
Character: {
label: 'Model_Data',
properties: {
fastRP_embedding:{property:'fastRP_Extended_Embedding', defaultValue:0},
strength:{property:'strength', defaultValue:0},
durability:{property:'durability', defaultValue:0},
intelligence:{property:'intelligence', defaultValue:0},
energy:{property:'energy', defaultValue:0},
speed:{property:'speed', defaultValue:0},
is_xman:{property:'is_xman', defaultValue:0}
}
},
Holdout_Character: {
label: 'Holdout_Data',
properties: {
fastRP_embedding:{property:'fastRP_Extended_Embedding', defaultValue:0},
strength:{property:'strength', defaultValue:0},
durability:{property:'durability', defaultValue:0},
intelligence:{property:'intelligence', defaultValue:0},
energy:{property:'energy', defaultValue:0},
speed:{property:'speed', defaultValue:0},
is_xman:{property:'is_xman', defaultValue:0}
}
}
}, {
APPEARED_WITH: {
type: 'APPEARED_WITH',
orientation: 'UNDIRECTED',
properties: ['times'],
aggregation: 'SINGLE'
}
});
```

Similar code like this ran before without any issues but no there is an error message regarding the data type of the default value:

> Failed to invoke procedure `gds.graph.project`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected type of default value to be `float[]`. But got `Long`

I already tried to change the default value for testing but the expected and got data types just change around.

I dont know whats the matter, all i found out is that it should just work with a defaultValue = 0.

Answer (score 0):

The node classification algorithms on this site: https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-data-science/node-classification/ is in BETA condition. It means it can go thru a lot of major changes. I suggest you go to https://github.com/AliciaFrame/ML_with_GDS for more tutorials.

Comment: I noticed that because i already had to change some things in the cypher code which changed. The code in the repository seems so be the same as on the webpage and not edited for a long time. I looked at this page [link](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/graph-project/) at table 4 and it should not be a problem to use a defaultValue with an Integer.